# Where condition not working on MySQL union 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

**Sorted!!!**

I have 2 tables, One table have person in charge for subscription. Second table have product users for each subscription and their details. I union both tables in mysql and query working 100% fine but when i try to filter records using where condition it return all the records without filtering.

Below you can find my query!

```
SELECT subscription_products.subscription_id, users.id, users.full_name,
users.company, users.job, users.birthday, users.gender,
users.nric, users.passport_number, users.phone_country_code,
users.phone_number, users.handphone_country_code, users.handphone_number,  
users.email, users.nationality, wallets.current_amount,
users.created_at, users.updated_at

FROM subscription_product_users
LEFT JOIN subscription_products
ON subscription_product_users.subscription_product_id = subscription_products.id
LEFT JOIN users
ON subscription_product_users.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN wallets
ON users.id = wallets.user_id

UNION

SELECT person_in_charge.subscription_id, person_in_charge.user_id,
users.full_name,
users.company, users.job, users.birthday, users.gender,
users.nric, users.passport_number, users.phone_country_code,
users.phone_number, users.handphone_country_code,
users.handphone_number, users.email, users.nationality, wallets.current_amount,
users.created_at, users.updated_at 

FROM person_in_charge
LEFT JOIN users
ON person_in_charge.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN wallets
ON person_in_charge.user_id = wallets.user_id

where subscription_id = '1378'
```

Can someone helps me?

Comment: Without seeing/knowing your data, we can only guess at what is happening here.  Please include sample data for best results.

Comment: The `where` clause only applies to the second select.

Comment: @Ravi answer worked for me. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap it and it work

```
 SELECT * FROM 

    (SELECT subscription_products.subscription_id, users.id, users.full_name,
    users.company, users.job, users.birthday, users.gender,
    users.nric, users.passport_number, users.phone_country_code,
    users.phone_number, users.handphone_country_code, users.handphone_number,  
    users.email, users.nationality, wallets.current_amount,
    users.created_at, users.updated_at

    FROM subscription_product_users
    LEFT JOIN subscription_products
    ON subscription_product_users.subscription_product_id = subscription_products.id
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON subscription_product_users.user_id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN wallets
    ON users.id = wallets.user_id

    UNION

    SELECT person_in_charge.subscription_id, person_in_charge.user_id,
    users.full_name,
    users.company, users.job, users.birthday, users.gender,
    users.nric, users.passport_number, users.phone_country_code,
    users.phone_number, users.handphone_country_code,
    users.handphone_number, users.email, users.nationality, wallets.current_amount,
    users.created_at, users.updated_at 

    FROM person_in_charge
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON person_in_charge.user_id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN wallets
    ON person_in_charge.user_id = wallets.user_id) 
as tempTable

where subscription_id = '1378'
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the filter in both the queries, also I have used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` to have better performance. If your query will return duplicates and you want to avoid it, then replace it with `UNION`

You need to start using Alias in queries like this.

```
SELECT sp.subscription_id, 
       u.id, 
       u.full_name, 
       u.company, 
       u.job, 
       u.birthday, 
       u.gender, 
       u.nric, 
       u.passport_number, 
       u.phone_country_code, 
       u.phone_number, 
       u.handphone_country_code, 
       u.handphone_number, 
       u.email, 
       u.nationality, 
       w.current_amount, 
       u.created_at, 
       u.updated_at 
FROM   subscription_product_users spu 
       INNER JOIN subscription_products sp 
               ON spu.subscription_product_id = sp.id 
       LEFT JOIN users u 
              ON spu.user_id = u.id 
       LEFT JOIN wallets w 
              ON u.id = w.user_id 
WHERE  sp.subscription_id = '1378' 
UNION ALL
SELECT pic.subscription_id, 
       pic.user_id, 
       u.full_name, 
       u.company, 
       u.job, 
       u.birthday, 
       u.gender, 
       u.nric, 
       u.passport_number, 
       u.phone_country_code, 
       u.phone_number, 
       u.handphone_country_code, 
       u.handphone_number, 
       u.email, 
       u.nationality, 
       w.current_amount, 
       u.created_at, 
       u.updated_at 
FROM   person_in_charge pic 
       LEFT JOIN users u 
              ON pic.user_id = u.id 
       LEFT JOIN wallets w 
              ON pic.user_id = w.user_id 
WHERE  pic.subscription_id = '1378'
```

Comment: @MalithPamudithaFernando Of course it will work, but I just showed you a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
select * from
(
    (select 1 as 'a')
    union
    (select 2 as 'a')
) as u
where
u.a=2
```

Comment: This does not attempt to address the issue OP has.